# How to map my Angular2 model to a json web api result

Tags: angular

I've created a simple Angular2 application to get a list of movies from an external web api (http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${keyword}). I get results in my application, but not the way I want.

I want to map the returned json to my Movie model in my MovieService.

This is what I have:

The model looks like this (movie.model.ts):

```
export class Movie {
    constructor(
        public Title:string,
        public Year:string,
        public imdbID:string,
        public Type:string,
        public Poster:string
    ){  }
}
```

movie.service.ts

```
// movie.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Movie } from '../models/movie.model';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

const makeUrl = (keyword) => `http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${keyword}`;

@Injectable()

export class MovieService {
    constructor(private http:Http){
    }   
        searchMovies(keyword)
        {
            return this.http.get(makeUrl (keyword))

                //.map(res => <Movie[]> res.json());
                .map(res => res.json())
                //.map(movies => <Movie[]> movies.Search);
                .map(movies => movies.Search);
        }
}
```

Below the app.components.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Movie } from './models/movie.model';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import {MovieService} from "./services/movie.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
  providers  : [MovieService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]

})
export class AppComponent { 
    public movies:Movie[] = [];
    public title:string = "My super movies!";

    constructor(private movieService:MovieService) {

    }

    searchMovies(keyword) {
        this.movieService.searchMovies(keyword)
            .subscribe(movieData => {
                    this.movies = movieData;                    // 1. success handler
                },
                err => console.log(err),                        // 2. error handler
                ()=> console.log('Getting movies complete...')  // 3. complete handler
            )

    }
}
```

This is my app.component.html

```
<!-- app.component.html -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Movies via OMDb API</h1>
        <div>
            <input type="text" #keyword class="input-lg" placeholder="movie name...">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="searchMovies(keyword.value)">Find movies</button>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Naam</th>
                <th>Jaar</th>
                <th>Poster</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let movie of movies">
                <td>{{ movie.Title }}</td>
                <td><span class="movieYear">{{ movie.Year}}</span></td>
                <td><img src="{{movie.Poster}}" alt="Movie" class="moviePoster"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

The application package.json, systemjs.config.js, tsconfig.json and typings.json are all from the [QuickStart tutorial on Angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#wrap-up)

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass your json data into your modal than you get you get your data in the form of data modal as you want.Try this code

```
export class Movie {
    constructor(
        public Title:string,
        public Year:string,
        public imdbID:string,
        public Type:string,
        public Poster:string
    ){  
           this.Title = data.title;
           this.Year = data.year;
           this.imdbID = data.imdbID;
           this.Type = data.Type;
           this.Poster = data.Poster;
      }
 }

    <.......>
    .....................................
    searchMovies(keyword) {
            this.movieService.searchMovies(keyword)
                .subscribe(movieData => {
                    for(let i=0; i<movieData.length ; i++){
                        this.movies.push(new Movie(movieData[i]));
                     }
                        console.log(this.movies);
                    },
                    err => console.log(err),
                    ()=> console.log('Getting movies complete...')
                )

        }
```

this will return your array in the form of your modal i.e Movie here. hope it helps.